# Не вызывается CallBack в Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

-

```
 val supportMapFragment = map as SupportMapFragment
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync { this }
```

Что я не так делаю. CallBack не вызывается.  `this` показывает ошибку `The expression is unused`

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Декомпилировал короче вот такак фигня получается

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.setContentView(2131296283);
      Fragment var10000 = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id.map);
      if(var10000 == null) {
         throw new TypeCastException("null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment");
      } else {
         SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)var10000;
         supportMapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback)(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            public final void onMapReady(GoogleMap it) {
               MapsActivity var10000 = MapsActivity.this;
            }
         }));
      }
   }
```

Почему Android Studio создается `new OnMapReadyCallback` Я же и так создал его и добавил this....

Comment: Больше кода добавьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Мдаа. Так накосячить это жесть. У меня студия автоматом ставит фигурные скобки вместо ()

Comment: видимо предполагается, что там будет реализация колбэка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фигурные скобки в Kotlin как раз и создают callback. То есть конструкция `{ this }` означает "создай callback, который при вызове будет получать this и ничего с ним не делать" (отсюда и предупреждение).

Если у вас this - это уже и есть нужный callback, то передавать его надо в круглых скобках вместо фигурных:

```
supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Или же вместо this можно написать тот код, который и должен выполняться:

```
supportMapFragment.getMapAsync {
    // тут надо писать код
}
```